# VIM indent not working properly with HTML files

Tags: html, vim, indentation

I'm trying to indent a HTML file with VIM,

```
<meta XXX >
```

As you can see, the meta tag is left open, but that is a common practice.

If I do a `ggVG=`, it become like this:

[image]

So VIM will not work unless it's closed properly. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: What version of vim are you running? I can't seem to reproduce the issue.  A copy of your vim configuration might also be useful.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you felt the need to post a screenshot instead of text in a code block?

Comment: Not only can I not reproduce the issue, but if i *start* with the bad text and `gg=G`, Vim *fixes* it for me to remove all indent. Do you have a custom html indent plugin installed? Do you have filetype-based indenting turned on? You're not doing something stupid like turning off filetype-based indent and turning on `'smartindent'`, are you?